# QGraphicsScene MouseMoveEvent connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Необходимо поймать событие `QGraphicsScene.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`. Код:

```
class CustomGraphView(QWidget):
 mainScene: QGraphicsScene
 mainGraphicsView: QGraphicsView

 def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.mainGraphicsView = QGraphicsView()
        self.mainGraphicsView.setScene(self.mainScene)

 def mouseMoveEvent(self, graphicsSceneMouseEvent: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):
     print('123')
```

Пытаюсь приконнектить так:

```
self.mainScene.mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent).connect(self.mouseMoveEvent)
```

Были попытки еще около десяти разных вариантов, но смысла постить их не вижу, так как результат очевиден в отрицательную сторону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нужно было включить маус трекиинг, причем не на виджете а на родительском выиджете, в данном случае `QGraphicsView`: